# AWS Athena Extract Array in Json

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a json column and inside this json column is an array structure. I couldn't figure out how to get the array there.

I trİed to this

```
 cast(json_extract(ise, '$.userservice') as varchar)  as ise_user_service
```

Example Json

```
ise
        {
       "userpa":"****",
       "userlo":"*****",
       "sessi":"******",
       "cl":{
          "name":"****",
          "id":"*****"
       },
       "usermains":"******",
       "userservice":[
          "1****",
          "23***4**",
          "124****",
          "034****"
       ],
       "usergeoloc":"********",
       "userparty":"*******"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [`json_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_format) to turn it into string or cast to `ARRAY(VARCHAR)` depending on the usecase:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       ( JSON ' {
       "userpa":"****",
       "userlo":"*****",
       "sessi":"******",
       "cl":{
          "name":"****",
          "id":"*****"
       },
       "usermains":"******",
       "userservice":[
          "1****",
          "23***4**",
          "124****",
          "034****"
       ],
       "usergeoloc":"********",
       "userparty":"*******"
    }')
 ) AS t (ise))

 
SELECT json_format(json_extract(ise, '$.userservice')) as ise_string, 
    cast(json_extract(ise, '$.userservice') as ARRAY(VARCHAR)) as ise_array
FROM dataset
```